# AG Grid: Add license before export

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, es6-modules, ag-grid-react

We use AG Grid. I want to add our license as a side effect before exporting the React component for use, rather than having to add the license every time we use the grid component.

What I tried below doesn't work. I thought side effects would run before import/export if declared like this, but clearly my mental model was wrong. I assume the build tool may affect what happens too, we use Gulp in this particular case.

**GridSupport.js** (in a design package/repo)

```js
/**
 * AG Grid License
 */
import { LicenseManager } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/core";
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey('…some license key…');

// Export below happens, but no license set above :(

export { AgGridReact as default } from "@ag-grid-community/react";
```

**Grid.js** (in another package/repo)

```
import { AgGridReact } from 'GridSupport';

const Grid = (props) => {
  // AgGridReact should be usable without printing license warnings to the console
  return <AgGridReact {...props} />
}
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: What is your build process ? do you have chunks ? Because if you do, it can mess thing up a little bit, with loading order beeing wrong. You need to be sure your GridSupport.js is loaded first

Comment: And also be sure both `@ag-grid-enterprise/core` and `@ag-grid-community/core` are on the same version, down to the patch number, because if they differ, they will not share the same license manager, because it will install two versions of `@ag-grid-community/core`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was edited to clarify that the two files were in two different packages.

We landed on adding the GridSupport.js to `sideEffects` in our design package/repo. This ensured that the license was set correctly as a side effect before the export happened.

**`package.json`**

```json
{
  "name": "@ourcompany/design",
  "sideEffects": [
    "some/path/GridSupport.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": [
    "ag-grid-community": "...",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "...",
    "ag-grid-react": "..."
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not Initialize the license manager at the top level (App.js, or index.js)? it would cover all the encompassing grids.
As a side note: Just make sure to check that you are not mixing packages and modules for the grid when using enterprise package.

Comment: Not visible from the question, but the two files are not actually in the same package. The Grid should be exported with the license from an internal design package, to be used in two or more other projects.